# Duplicate form entries: How to send through to mysql database

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have a page where a user can create a recipe. I have a javascript script that allows the user to keep adding form input elements for more ingredients. Say the recipe has 4 ingredients the user can continue to add inputs. However this changes the id to ingredient1/2/3/4 for the input ID/Name,and i can't understand how to get around getting the information from the form post as the amount of elements is upto user discretion. How would you go about loading the results into PHP variables and then inserting them into a mysql query.

the syntax for the html form

```
<div id="ingredient1" class="clonedInput">
                <h2 class="first-column">Ingredient</h2>
                <span style="float:left; padding-right: 10px;">
                <input type="text" name="scroll" value="Add Ingredient" id="ingredient" class="ingredient"/>
                </span>
</div>
```

ingredient1 would change to ingredient2 for the purpose 2 ingredient's being added.

A slightly confusing problem, so any help would be amazing!

JB

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is using `[]` in your input element names.  This will post the data as an array.  So, say you have this as your form's ingredient input elements (after javascript has added several):

```
<input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="" />
```

When the user POST's the data, you will be able to access the array of ingredients at `$_POST['ingredients']`

Comment: so for every element it would be name="ingredients[]" not name="ingredients[1]"? I can easily code it if its without the numerical identifier

Comment: Yes this works.  This is the ideal way to handle posting of array type data of unspecified length.  You can also use `ingredients[1]`, `ingredients[2]`, etc. if you wanted to be very specific about the index ordering, but for the most part when cloning input elements with javascript it is much easier to just use `[]` notation.

Comment: Perfect, with this data, how could i add this array into an mysql insert form. So to just paste all the ingredients in the same field? :).

Comment: @JBUCL You probably don;t want to insert all ingredients in the same field. I properly normalized database would have a recipes tables, an ingredients table and an recipes to ingredients table.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you the logic, not the code as only javascript here would not be enough.

1. you create a table ingredients. Anything you can allow them to use. id, ecc
2. while posting, instead of doing giving the user a freedom chosing their ingredient1, ingredient2 ... you do load from ingredients table the values and index them as ingredient[id_from_db] ecc..
3. you create a table recipe. It should have a unique id, its description
4. you create a relation table recipe_id, ingredient_id

then when the user post its data you create 1 row in the recipe and as many rows in the relation table as the ingredients they use.

When selecting later the recipe you also select everything which is in the relation table, it could be several rows there...

Hope it is of any help for you. Can't show you any code for this, but it is not hard to make if you understand how it goes.

maxim